# FileNotFoundException Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, audio-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to make a mediaplayer in android streaming songs from Amazon S3.
I made the songs in my bucket public and it works fine when I stream them with the bowser.
But when it come to android, it throws me an exception like that.

```
11-20 01:28:37.720: W/System.err(736): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /https:/s3.amazonaws.com/soul-media/mp3s/1234.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

here is my code for the player

```
    MediaPlayer mid= new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        FileInputStream fid= new FileInputStream("https://s3.amazonaws.com/soul-media/mp3s/1234.mp3");
        mid.setDataSource(fid.getFD());
        mid.prepare();
        mid.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It worked with android 4.1 but did not work with 2.2, can that be the issue?
I also tried some urls other than Amazon S3, it works. So is that something with Amazon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't just skip creating the `FileInputStream` and call `mid.setDataSource("https://s3.amazonaws.com/...")` via [this overload](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29)? Does that work?

Edit:
Apparently, instead of calling `prepare` for streams, you should be calling `prepareAsync` which should return immediately, like so:

```
MediaPlayer mid = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    mid.setDataSource("http://soul-media.s3.amazonaws.com/mp3s/1234.mp3");
    mid.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mid.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    mid.prepareAsync();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, I'v tried that too. But it gives me an error says : Parpare Failed

Comment: Ooh, I've got it. I think maybe the MediaPlayer doesn't support HTTPS, so you need the HTTP URL, which is different. Use this: "http://soul-media.s3.amazonaws.com/mp3s/1234.mp3"

Editing source accordingly. Got this to work on my machine.